# Pair values in two columns and check value of third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| amount | IZ Ref | Fee | Fee paired with IZ ref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **7.1** | 1 | 10.2 | yes |
| **55.89** | 2 |  | yes |
| 22.1 |  | **7.1** | yes |
| 200.12 |  |  | no |
| 333.1 |  | 404.45 | no |
| 609 | 6 | **55.89** | yes |
| 525 |  | 32.22 | no |

I need a formula for the last column:
yes = if value from `fee` is matched to at least one value in `amount`, but only if `IZ ref` next to that amount is not blank.

So, `IZ Ref` qualifies the `amount` for comparison.

if `IZ Ref` is blank in the row where `fee` is taken from, that should also be Yes, because `IZ ref` will be found in the row where `amount` is matched.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try: `=IF(AND(OR(B2<>"",C2<>""),SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8=C2)+($C$2:$C$8=A2))),"Yes","No")`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF(AND(OR(B2<>"",C2<>""),SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8=C2)+($C$2:$C$8=A2))),"Yes","No")
```

---

Or, try this one:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$8)),ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$8)),B2<>""),"Yes","No")
```

---